# can not build imported source from git JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I use eclipse for my java coding and just imported some java source from git with below method.
(right click --> import --> projects from git)
it seems codes were downloaded successfully but I can't build it. 
in menu bar, Project --> Build project is not working for my downloaded source.
someone said "check your project icon in the package explorer, your little "J" on the files is too faint it means you did not commit your project metadata files properly". how can I fix this issue? please refer my picture below(my current issue) and give me your kind advice.

[my current issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbnR6.jpg)

Comment: What is the "type" of the project?

Comment: it is not a complete but by the looks of it, it seems that you have two separate modules in you project, one is your current project and the other is your checked out project  from git ... elaborate more on your problem

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i always clone project from repository using terminal and command:

```
git clone <repo url>
```

and then in Eclipse, import existing project directly from hard drive.